# Should Framebusting be used (not used) on an IdP login page?

Tags: web-application, authentication, appsec, openid

I'm trying to understand when [Framebusting](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/613/396) should and shouldn't be used.  At first brush I'd want to apply that to all pages in my site and generating exceptions as necessary.

On the other hand, if I were to take a minimalist approach, I would think I would want to apply this security to my login page.

- Is there any reason why I shouldn't apply framebusting to a login page?
- Are there any other related best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen Framebusting as a technique is becoming somewhat deprecated as a defence against click-jacking style attacks in favour of setting the X-Frame-Options header (e.g. the OWASP page [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) and [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)).  Browser support for the X-Frame-Options headers seems to go back to IE8 so unless you have a really old set of browsers to support it should work ok.

So the short answer is that I'd recommend going down that line rather than using Framebusting Javascript.

Comment: So I should use X-Frame-Options on all pages in a site? ... likely starting at the login page?

Comment: I'd say so, If the site doesn't require frames at all then I'd see no downside to setting X-FRAME-OPTIONS 'DENY' for all pages.